# Manhwa about a female lead who is planning revenge

Tags: story-identification, manga

There's a scene on Tiktok where a guy with blonde hair saw a girl (black hair if I’m not mistaken) who was crying and sad, but when he looked closer he saw her smiling like something between being a serial killer or a crazy woman (and maybe she also has a fan in her hands). He was shocked that she pretends to be sad (I partly remember it was a funeral but I’m not sure).

It is happening in a simulation of the Middle ages; maybe it is an isekai.

Comment: What the heck is a TT?

Comment: Tiktok, TT is an abbreviated version

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Planning revenge on whom?  And where/when did you read this?

Comment: @Drakos As you can see, abbreviations are confusing to people; there's no requirement to shave characters from a post here, so it's better if you spell things out.

Comment: Well, I just watched some videos on Tiktok and saw the short video with the fragment of manhwa. It looked like fl was trying to look nice while plotting behind the backs of her enemies. The key point was her evil smile, and this blonde dude didn’t expect it. About revenge: it looked like she was trying to destroy her family or maybe some ppl from government, Idk cause I saw just a fragment and sadly it was deleted :’) I haven’t read it yet, before I was trying to find it on Pinterest, YouTube but didn’t find anything

Comment: Ok, got you! :)

Comment: I found it! 
So the name is Concentration of Malice: https://youtube.com/shorts/pOOuJhnyeqw?feature=share

Comment: Glad to hear you found it. Could you post that as an answer, and include some details from the story? This will make it clear to others that it's answered and makes the story more visible to others that might be interested in it.